# Persist WTForm QuerySelectField value after get request

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm looking for a clean way to persist WTFForm QuerySelectField values when a given drop down option is selected. The idea is to filter a list of projects according to the given technology selected from the QuerySelectField drop down. The approach I've taken is to send a get request to /projects containing a query string with the technology id using an on change event on the drop down i.e. /projects?id=5.
I have it structured in the following way:

Project form-

```
class ProjectForm(ProjectFormBase):
   title = StringField('Title', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25), validators.DataRequired()])
   technology = QuerySelectField('Technology', query_factory= connect.technology_choices,
                    get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
                    get_label=lambda a: a.name, allow_blank=True, blank_text=u'Select a technology...')
```

Project route-

```
@app.route('/projects', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects():
    list_of_projects = None
    form = ProjectForm(request.form)
    technology_id = request.args.get('id')
    if technology_id:
       list_of_projects = connect.project(technology_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if list_of_projects:
            connect.close_connection()
            return render_template("projects.html", 
                                    list_of_projects = list_of_projects, form = form)
        else:
            return render_template("projects.html", form=form)
```

JS -

```
$('#technology').on('change', function () {
        var technology = $("#technology").value;
        window.location.href="/projects?id=" + technology_id;
        window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', '/projects');
    });
```

Just to summarise, I'm looking for the chosen dropdown menu value to persist after the on change event. I'm also open to a completely different approach rather than passing query string values in as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you need now is for the Technology select field to be set when the page is requested with the GET arg `id` set.  Something like this should work:

```
@app.route('/projects', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects():
    form = ProjectForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        technology_id = request.args.get('id')
        # Set selected option on select field.
        form.technology.data = technology_id
        try:
            list_of_projects = connect.project(technology_id)
            connect.close_connection()
        except:
            list_of_projects = []

        return render_template("projects.html",
                               list_of_projects=list_of_projects, form=form)
```

I also suggest removing some code to conform with Python's EAFP design principle.